# Change the location of Kentico SmartSearch Index to Azure Blob

Tags: azure, kentico

Is it possible to change the location where the Smartsearch Index is being saved? i would like to save it to my own Azure Blob. and also, i would like to also make the smartsearch point to the same azure blob once the user used smartsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the location of index files by following web.config settings

```
<add key="CMSSearchIndexPath" value="App_Data\MyCustomIndexes" />
```

If you'll have the same folder mapped to external storage it should theoretically work

```
StorageHelper.MapStoragePath("~/MySite/Media/", mediaProvider);
```

See how to [configure the storage](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Configuring+Azure+storage).

Comment: if my understanding is correct, this would work only if i have existing Indices on the folder "App_Data\MyCustomIndexes" and the second line of code will then copy the files from App_Data\MyCustomIndexes to the Azure blob. but i would want the smartsearch to read the indices directly from azure blob

Comment: Not really. `MapStoragePath` virtually redirects all IO request trough the mapped provider. So it should read/write directly to the blob.